# Formdata image file isn't being caught by API call

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I am using JavaScript to create an API call and send it to a corresponding Asp.Net Core function.

JavaScript:

```
function fileSubmit() {
        var data = document.getElementById("myFile").files; //it should be noted that this successfully catches the file.
        var formData = new FormData();        
        formData.append("files", data);         

        var url = "http://localhost/api/Surveys/123456/Units/987654/Images";        
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", url, true);        
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "image/jpeg"); 
        xhr.send(formData);       
}
```

.Net Core:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("{Id:int:min(1)}/Units/{unitId:int:min(1)}/Images")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IAPIResponse2<UploadImagesResponse>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IAPIResponse2<UploadImagesResponse>), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImages([FromForm, Required] IList<IFormFile> files)
{
       //do stuff
}
```

I am able to create and send the API call and it is caught by the Asp.Net function, but the `files` parameter is empty. The file list is successfully appended to the `formData` object in the JavaScript function, as far as I know.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your JavaScript code above:

1. `files` is being sent incorrectly. If you look at the request, you'll see it's a bit confused and includes `[object FileList]` as part of the body.

To solve this issue, you'll want to iterate through the files and add them individually:

```
var files = document.getElementById("myFile").files;
var formData = new FormData();

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    formData.append("files", files[i]);
}
```

If you *are* just sending the one file, you could simplify this:

```
var files = document.getElementById("myFile").files;
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("files", files[0]);
```

2. You should not set the `Content-Type` header when making the request.

To solve this issue, simply remove your call to `setRequestHeader`. The `Content-Type` header will be set by the XHR process to be `multipart/form-data` with boundaries (see the [RFC](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) for the Multipart Content-Type).

> Each part starts with an encapsulation boundary, and then contains a body part consisting of header area, a blank line, and a body area.

Due to the way this is structured, the `Content-Type` is specified on a per-file basis. If you are interested, have a look at the request in the developer tools once you've made the changes I have detailed.